# Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length'

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo php me salta el error del titulo

```
public function traer_testis($id) {

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM testimonios WHERE id_testimonio ="'.$id.'"';

        $rs = $this->consulta($sql);

        $datos = array();
        //$registros = "";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $registros = new stdClass();
            $registros->id_testimonio = $row["id_testimonio"];
            $registros->nombre_testimonio = $row["nombre_testimonio"];
            $registros->descripcion_testimonio = $row["descripcion_testimonio"];
            $registros->descripciond_testimonio = $row["descripciond_testimonio"];
            $registros->lugar_testimonio = $row["lugar_testimonio"];
            $registros->color_testimonio = $row["color_testimonio"];
            $registros->puesto_testimonio = $row["puesto_testimonio"];
            $registros->img_testimonio = $row["img_testimonio"];
            $datos[] = $registros;


        }
        if ($datos.length == 0) {
            $registros = '<tr>';
            $registros .= '<td colspan="5">';
            $registros .= 'No existen registros ...';
            $registros .= '</td>';
            $registros .= '</tr>';
        }

        //$arr = array('registros' => $registros);
        //return ($arr);
        return  ($datos);
    }
```

luego al retornar el objeto me sale otro error

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\teo360\dashmin\clases\adminteo.class.php on line 57

este es el otro codigo

```
    <?php 
        require_once '../clases/adminteo.class.php';

        $id = $_POST['seleccionado'];

        $adminteo = new adminteos();
        $datos = $adminteo->traer_testis($id);
        echo json_encode($datos);

?>
```

Comment: Como ya se ha dicho en respuesta, para saber cuántos elementos hay en un array debes usar `count($array);`. Ahora bien lo que hay dentro de este if en tu código: `if ($datos.length == 0) {...}` **no parece tener ninguna utilidad**, ya que tú haces un `return $datos;` al final de la función. ¿Se puede saber entonces para que sirve esa parte...? Además. en el `while` tratas a `$registros` como un objeto, pues usas `->` y en el `if` tratas a la misma variable como una simple cadena. ¿?

Answer (score 2):

Es debido a que `array` en php no contiene una propiedad `length`. Utiliza el metodo [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
if (count($datos) == 0) {
    $registros = '<tr>';
    $registros .= '<td colspan="5">';
    $registros .= 'No existen registros ...';
    $registros .= '</td>';
    $registros .= '</tr>';
 }
```